# non-standard characters cause program to end

Tags: python, python-2.7, text-mining

I am learning python for data mining and I have a text file that contains a list of world cities and their coordinates. With my code, I am trying to find the coordinates of a list of cities. Everything works well until there is a city name with non-standard characters. I expect the program will skip that name and move to the next, but it terminates. How will I make the program skip names it cannot find and continue to the next?

```
lst = ['Paris', 'London', 'Helsinki', 'Amsterdam', 'Sant Julià de Lòria',
       'New York', 'Dublin']
source = 'world.txt'
fh = open(source)
n = 0
for line in fh:
    line.rstrip()

    if lst[n] not in line:
        continue
    else:
        co = line.split(',')
        print lst[n], 'Lat: ', co[5], 'Long: ', co[6]

        if n < (len(lst)-1):
            n = n + 1
        else:
            break
```

The outcome of this run is:

```
>>>
Paris Lat:  33.180704 Long:  67.470836

London Lat:  -11.758217 Long:  17.084013

Helsinki Lat:  60.175556 Long:  24.934167

Amsterdam Lat:  6.25 Long:  -57.5166667

>>>
```

Comment: Can you maybe attach your file, too? Probably the content does not match up exactly. Also, consider using context managers, that is: `with open(source, 'r') as handle: for line in handle.readlines():`, since you don't close your handle right now.

Comment: Note that `line.rstrip()` does not do anything.  String functions return a new string, they do not alter an existing string because strings are *immutable*.  `line=line.rstrip()`.

Comment: The file has more than 3 million lines; it is huge. The name is present in the file exactly as it is in the list though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a number of issues. The following fixes most, if not all, of them — and should never terminate when a city isn't found.

```
# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-
from __future__ import print_function

cities = ['Paris', 'London', 'Helsinki', 'Amsterdam', 'Sant Julià de Lòria', 'New York',
          'Dublin']
SOURCE = 'world.txt'

for city in cities:
    with open(SOURCE) as fh:
        for line in fh:
            if city in line:
                fields = line.split(',')
                print(fields[0], 'Lat: ', fields[5], 'Long: ', fields[6])
                break
```

Comment: Also note that this does a linear search, potentially through the entire file, for each city processed. It would be _much_ faster to first read  and store the entire file into memory — as either a list or dictionary — and then process each city in the list using that.

Answer (score 0):

It may be an encoding problem. You have to know in which encoding is the file "world.txt".

If you do not know it, try the most commonly used encodings.

Replace the line :

```
fh = open(source)
```

With the lines :

```
import codecs
fh = codecs.open(source, 'r', 'utf-8')
```

If it still does not work, replace the `'utf-8'` by `'cp1252'`, then by `'iso-8859-1'`.
If none of these common encoding works, you have to find the encoding by yourself. Try to open "world.txt" in Notepad++, this text editor is able to make encoding inference. (Not sure if Notepad++ is able to open a 3 million line files, though).

It is also a good practice to know in which encoding is your own python source file, and to tell it explicitly by adding a line like that `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the beginning of your source file.

Of course, you have to specify the exact encoding in which your source file is. Once again, you can determine it by opening it in Notepad++.